# Identifying finance related words from a document using python

Tags: python, nltk, text-mining, wordnet

I've been given a task to identify all the finance related words from documents. Do I need a finance wordnet (as we do for sentiment analysis) or do I need a dictionary containing finance words?

Comment: I would suggest [Regular Expression](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html) and a dictionary containing finance words.

Comment: Identify them how?  Just a yes/no? count them? Frequency Histogram? Position on the Page?

Comment: @Kingsley identifying and displaying the words only